# Get hierarchical Data From Neo4j To C# Object Structure using Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have get in to a situation that need to Load a hierarchical object Graph from Neo4j into C# using neo4jClient

I have a post Class in C# as fallow:

```
public class Post : BaseNode
{
    public Post Parent { get; set; }
    public float Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICollection<HashTag> HashTags { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IKeyCommand> KeyTags { get; set; }
    public ICollection<NeoDateTime> DueDates { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser Author { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IdentityUser> MentionedUsers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Team> MentionedTeam { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PostAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }

}
```

and Here is my Graph : 
[image: ThePost Graph]

Now Imagin a method wich need to load all the parent of a graph with all its related properties using parent Id

I have Came up with this C# Code which Produce needed Cypher :

```
public IList<Post> LoadParents(int id)
    {
        var matchStringTemplate = "(post:Post {{Id:{0}}})-[r:HAS_Parent*]->(parents:Post)";
        var matchString = string.Format(matchStringTemplate, id);

        var q = new CypherFluentQuery(_graphClient) as ICypherFluentQuery;
        q = q.Match(string.Format(matchStringTemplate, id));

        q = q.OptionalMatch("(post:Post)-[mentionedUsersRelation:HAS_MentionedUsers]->(allAssignees:User)");
        q = q.OptionalMatch("(post:Post)-[authorRelation:HAS_Author]->(author:User)");
        q = q.OptionalMatch("(post:Post)-[hashtagRElation:HAS_HashTags]->(hashtags:HashTag)");
        q = q.OptionalMatch("(post:Post)-[HasAttachmentRelation:HAS_Attachments]->(attachment:PostAttachment)");

        q = q.OptionalMatch("(parents:Post)-[pmentionedUsersRelation:HAS_MentionedUsers]->(pallAssignees:User)");
        q = q.OptionalMatch("(parents:Post)-[pauthorRelation:HAS_Author]->(pauthor:User)");
        q = q.OptionalMatch("(parents:Post)-[phashtagRElation:HAS_HashTags]->(phashtags:HashTag)");
        q = q.OptionalMatch("(parents:Post)-[pHasAttachmentRelation:HAS_Attachments]->(pattachment:PostAttachment)");

        var rq = q.Return((post, parents,  allAssignees, author, hashtags, attachment,

            pallAssignees, pauthor, phashtags, pattachment) => new
        {
            Post = post.As<Post>(),
            Parent = parents.As<Post>(),
            Author = author.As<IdentityUser>(),
            MentionedUsers = allAssignees.CollectAsDistinct<IdentityUser>(),
            Attachments = attachment.CollectAsDistinct<PostAttachment>(),
            HashTags = hashtags.CollectAsDistinct<HashTag>()
        })
        .OrderByDescending("post.CreationDate");

        var result = rq.Results;
        var results = result.Select(p => new Post()
        {
            Id = p.Post.Id,

            Text = p.Post.Text,
            CreationDate = p.Post.CreationDate,
            Author = p.Author,
            MentionedUsers = p.MentionedUsers.Select(m => m.Data).ToArray(),
            HashTags = p.HashTags.Select(h => h.Data).ToArray(),
            Attachments = p.Attachments.Select(a => a.Data).ToArray()
        });
        return results.ToList();
    }
```

the Cypher would be something like this:

```
 MATCH (post:Post {Id:9601})-[r:HAS_Parent*]->(parents:Post)

OPTIONAL MATCH (post:Post)-[mentionedUsersRelation:HAS_MentionedUsers]->(allAssignees:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (post:Post)-[authorRelation:HAS_Author]->(author:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (post:Post)-[hashtagRElation:HAS_HashTags]->(hashtags:HashTag)
OPTIONAL MATCH (post:Post)-[HasAttachmentRelation:HAS_Attachments]->(attachment:PostAttachment)
OPTIONAL MATCH (parents:Post)-[pmentionedUsersRelation:HAS_MentionedUsers]->(pallAssignees:User)

OPTIONAL MATCH (parents:Post)-[pauthorRelation:HAS_Author]->(pauthor:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (parents:Post)-[phashtagRElation:HAS_HashTags]->(phashtags:HashTag)
OPTIONAL MATCH (parents:Post)-[pHasAttachmentRelation:HAS_Attachments]->(pattachment:PostAttachment)
RETURN post AS Post, collect(distinct parents) AS Parent, author AS Author, collect(distinct allAssignees) AS MentionedUsers, collect(distinct attachment) AS Attachments, collect(distinct hashtags) AS HashTags
ORDER BY post.CreationDate DESC
```

But the problem is I dont kow how to load the result into the hierarchy strutuer of node and its parent in the post C# class.

the cypher result is what i am looking for when I test the query on db. but everything get messed up in C# object.

here is the query result in neo4jDB:

[image: Post Parents]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Post class has multiple parents posts, then I think you should change

```
public Post Parent { get; set; }
```

to something like

```
public IEnumerable<Post> Parent { get; set; }
```

Then you can map all parent nodes in cypher result to this property

Comment: No, My post Class has only one parent. and each parent could also have one parent.
it's a self reference hierarchy.

Comment: Then, I think, You should use special class for result of query. Not the Post class.